# What are the most important structured software design principles?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, software-design, design-principles

Today I saw a job description that requires "significant experience coding in C++ and a thorough grounding in structured design principles", so I thought about what these principles are. First I felt it was a little odd to see C++ and "structured design" in one sentence, then I thought, OK C++ is a multi-paradigm programming language, so perhaps it's used like C. I also looked up the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) and read about exception handling and state machines are anti structured design (no surprise), but I still feel like many things are missing. So I'm asking you, what are the most important structured software design principles?

Comment: I think this question should be CW, since there is no definitive right answer for this.

Comment: Smells like a BS job title put together by a clueless person. Go ahead and ask them. Your downside is exposing the fact that they are clueless.

Comment: @Anthony: there really was a well-developed methodology called 'structured design', developed at IBM in the 1970s.  The two main principles were coupling and cohesion.  Whether the job description actually meant to ask about this methodology is unknowable, but the question as posed certainly has a definitive right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structured programming and structured design wouldn't necessarily be the same thing.  Structured design in general is going to focus on breaking things down into structured elements.  There are a bunch of approaches that are equally valid here, but I would say that most of them focus on information hiding.

- Object Oriented Design obviously breaks things down into objects with operations and data held together in tightly bound classes related in hierarchies
- Abstract Data Types are essentially non-OO equivalents where the data and operations are held together but are not bound in quite the same sense as in object oriented design.  Hierarchy and inheritance don't play a role with ADTs, at least not in those that I've seen.
- Metaprogramming focuses on building generic types and then specializing them appropriately for specific data types
- Programming to a contract focuses on avoiding direct inheritance.  Typically it combines Contract Interfaces with implementation by composition of multiple classes.
- Design Patterns focus on high-level meta-designs (patterns) that can be implemented in almost any context, although they are most commonly seen in discussions of OO design.

Knowing how to structure programs in multiple paradigms is always going to be valuable knowledge.  Knowing how to talk about the structure of a design is more finicky but ultimately even more valuable.

Comment: I think most answers here are a bit off, but I liked this one the best because it tried to examine multiple design methodologies.  What you fail to take into account is that Methodology != Process.  Most Structured Analysis & Design books I own usually advocate a process for decomposing requirements e.g. usually into data flow diagrams and Floyd-style flow charts.  The major problem with this Process view in Structured Design is that the code becomes spaghetti, because you model individual requirements and not the context in which "objects" interact.  This was the major A-Ha! idea for OOP.

Comment: Sorry user429921, but I don't agree at all with your edits.  You basically removed the explanation of what they are in favour of explaining their purpose.  If you honestly think the above explanation of the structures themselves is incorrect, add your own answer.  I would consider your edit of the OOD section, for example, to be Object Based Design, not OOD.  The difference in my mind is that OOD tends to take advantage of the ability to build hierarchies, whereas OBD tends to eschew those capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

In the classic works on composite/structured design by [Myers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0442805845) and by [Yourdon and Constantine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0138544719), the two most important principles are

- Coupling (how different modules relate to one another)
- Cohesion (how a module is structured internally)

I agree with Mike Burton that the author of the ad probably lacks a clue, but you can brush up on "module coupling" and "module cohesion" easily enough, and if you can get them at a library, the books are worth reading.  I can find [the original paper](http://dret.net/biblio/reference/ste74) only at an IBM pay site.

Comment: Thanks Norman. My wife is an IBMer so I will ask her to get this paper for me.

Answer (score 1):

What I always refer to is a ancient article in IEEE Micro Magazine October 1981 by G. D. Bergland of Bell Telephone Laboritories - belive it or not.  It's about thirteen pages long and gives you most everything you need to know.  Trouble is you may not be able to find it - even at IEEE & even if your a member.

You can find another very good (though old) book "Tutorial on Software Design Techniques" by Peter Freeman (Editor) at Amazon.

http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0818605146/ref=dp_olp_0?ie=UTF8&redirect=true&condition=all

Comment: What was the name of the article? In the whole index if IEEE Micro (http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/toc/ieeemicro.html) I cannot find the name "G. D. Bergland"